# sql - count one column based on another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a dataset

```
case_id    subcase_id
1      | 1-1
1      | 1-2
1      | 1-3
1      | 1-6
2      | 2-1
2      | 2-7
```

I want the following output. The idea is to count the occurence of a subcase corresponding to a case.

```
case_id  subcase_id
1      | 1-1          | 1
1      | 1-2          | 2
1      | 1-3          | 3
1      | 1-6          | 4
2      | 2-1          | 1
2      | 2-7          | 2
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: I am using oracle 12

Comment: Please remove the MySQL tag. Oracle <> Mysql

Comment: Does the leading number in `subcase_id` always map to the `case_id` ? Can the trailing number in the `subcase_id` extend into two or more digits? Does it matter what order the count is in?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using row_number() function

```
select 
   caseid,
   subcase_id, 
   row_number() over(partition by caseid 
      order by 
      cast(SUBSTR(subcase_id, 1,INSTR(subcase_id, '-') -1) as number), 
      cast(SUBSTR(subcase_id, INSTR(subcase_id, '-') +1) as number)) as rn
from tablename
```

Comment: This might not sort properly with a `subcase_id` like `10-12`, because then it would sort as _text_, and not as separate numbers.

Comment: Yes I know @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: [Check this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=193f899590ff345114dfcba2a99c5d86) to see what I mean ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks I knew that it's string and I need to split it and then convert it to number

Answer (score 1):

You may use `count() over (partition by .. order by ..)` clause as :

```
    with t(case_id,subcase_id) as
    (   
     select 1,'1-1' from dual union all
     select 1,'1-2' from dual union all
     select 1,'1-3' from dual union all
     select 1,'1-6' from dual union all
     select 2,'2-1' from dual union all
     select 2,'2-7' from dual
    )
     select t.*,
            count(*) over (partition by case_id order by subcase_id)              
            as result
       from t;

    CASE_ID     SUBCASE_ID   RESULT
    -------     ----------   ------ 
       1            1-1        1
       1            1-2        2
       1            1-3        3
       1            1-6        4
       2            2-1        1
       2            2-7        2
```

*where subcase_id is changes frequently and distinct for all values while case_id changes rarely.*

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ITQVC57174)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query which should behave as you want.  We have to isolate the two numeric components of the `subcase_id`, and then cast them to integers, to avoid sorting this column as text.

```
SELECT
    case_id,
    subcase_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY case_id
        ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(subcase_id, 1, INSTR(subcase_id, '-') - 1)),
                 TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(subcase_id, INSTR(subcase_id, '-') + 1))) rn
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    case_id,
    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(subcase_id, 1, INSTR(subcase_id, '-') - 1)),
    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(subcase_id, INSTR(subcase_id, '-') + 1));
```

### Demo

It is not a good idea to treat the `subcase_id` column as both text and numbers.  If you really have a long term need to sort on this column, then I suggest breaking out the two numeric components as separate number columns.